# makedumpfile with vmcoreinfo fails with "check_release:(null) and /proc/vmcore don't match."

Tags: linux-kernel

I prepared a crash kernel (using kexec) which should dump /proc/vmcore into a core dump using makedumpfile: version 1.6.7; kernel version is rt-5.4

Since vmlinux is too large for the crash kernel I first generated a vmcoreinfo file in the first kernel as follows:

`makedumpfile -g vmcoreinfo -x vmlinux`

In the crash kernel makedumpfile is then called as follows:

`/usr/bin/makedumpfile -i /boot/vmcoreinfo -E -d1 /proc/vmcore /var/crash/2004-04-25/vmcore-19:16:02`

I keep getting the error message:

`check_release:`**`(null)`** `and /proc/vmcore don't match`

(null) is the string in "info->name_vmcoreinfo". The "-i" option correctly sets "info->name_vmcoreinfo" to /boot/vmcoreinfo.

If I look at the source (https://github.com/makedumpfile/makedumpfile/blob/Released-1-6-7/makedumpfile.c). I see that "read_vmcoreinfo_from_vmcore" (line 4154) overwrites "info->name_vmcoreinfo" to (null) which leads top the (null) in the error message.

```
    /*
     * Get the debug information from /proc/vmcore.
     * NOTE: Don't move this code to the above, because the debugging
     *       information token by -x/-i option is overwritten by vmcoreinfo
     *       in /proc/vmcore. vmcoreinfo in /proc/vmcore is more reliable
     *       than -x/-i option.
     */
    if (has_vmcoreinfo()) {
        get_vmcoreinfo(&offset, &size);
        if (!read_vmcoreinfo_from_vmcore(offset, size, FALSE))
            return FALSE;
        debug_info = TRUE;
    }
```

Am I using makedumpfile in the right way? Or what else can be wrong?

BR, Chris